# Crash reports sent according to logcat but didn't show in Arcalyzer Dashboard?

Tags: android, acra

I am creating an arithmetic exception to receive crash report using ARCA. I have set up back end at Cloudant using arcalyzer. After a crash, According to logcat, the crash report has been sent but no report is being shown at the arcalyzer dashboard.
Couldn't figure out what is wrong with this code.

MainApp:

```
@ReportsCrashes(
    formUri = "https://terrybogard911.cloudant.com/acra-faheemcallrecorder/_design/acra-storage/_update/report",
    reportType = HttpSender.Type.JSON,
    httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST,
    formUriBasicAuthLogin = ""//Login,
    formUriBasicAuthPassword = ""//Password,
    customReportContent = {
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
            ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
            ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME,
            ReportField.REPORT_ID,
            ReportField.BUILD,
            ReportField.STACK_TRACE
    },
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    resToastText = R.string.toast_crash

)
public class MainApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ACRA.init(this);
}
}
```

Logcat:

```
09-14 01:32:08.546 19876-19876/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder E/ACRA: ACRA caught a ArithmeticException for com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder
                                                                                                                                                      java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
                                                                                                                                                          at com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:228)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2644)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:408)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:679)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:156)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:969)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:127)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1158)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2957)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3849)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5107)
                                                                                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
                                                                                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
                                                                                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 01:32:08.546 19876-19876/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Building report
09-14 01:32:08.556 19876-19876/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Using custom Report Fields
09-14 01:32:08.646 19876-19876/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder I/ACRA: READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
09-14 01:32:08.646 19876-19876/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Writing crash report file 1505334728000.stacktrace.
09-14 01:32:08.656 19876-19876/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: About to start ReportSenderWorker from #handleException
09-14 01:32:08.666 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Mark all pending reports as approved.
09-14 01:32:08.666 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Looking for error files in /data/data/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder/files
09-14 01:32:08.676 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: #checkAndSendReports - start
09-14 01:32:08.696 19876-20037/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Waiting for 2000 millis from 1505334728625 currentMillis=1505334728707
09-14 01:32:08.696 19876-20039/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Waiting for Toast
09-14 01:32:08.696 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Looking for error files in /data/data/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder/files
09-14 01:32:08.696 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder I/ACRA: Sending file 1505334728000-approved.stacktrace
09-14 01:32:08.766 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Connect to https://terrybogard911.cloudant.com/acra-faheemcallrecorder/_design/acra-storage/_update/report
09-14 01:32:08.796 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Sending request to https://terrybogard911.cloudant.com/acra-faheemcallrecorder/_design/acra-storage/_update/report
09-14 01:32:08.806 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder E/DataScheduler: isDataSchedulerEnabled():false
09-14 01:32:09.576 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder V/TlsSniSocketFactory: Setting allowed TLS protocols: TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
09-14 01:32:09.576 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder V/TlsSniSocketFactory: Setting allowed TLS ciphers: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
09-14 01:32:09.576 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/TlsSniSocketFactory: Using documented SNI with host name terrybogard911.cloudant.com
09-14 01:32:10.266 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder I/TlsSniSocketFactory: Established TLSv1.2 connection with terrybogard911.cloudant.com using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
09-14 01:32:10.636 19876-20036/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: #checkAndSendReports - finish
09-14 01:32:10.706 19876-20039/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Finished waiting for Toast
09-14 01:32:10.706 19876-20039/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Waiting for Worker
09-14 01:32:10.706 19876-20039/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Finished waiting for Worker
09-14 01:32:10.706 19876-20039/com.tookmesomuchtime.javaprogramming.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder D/ACRA: Wait for Toast + worker ended. Kill Application ? true
```

Comment: which acra version are you using?

Comment: I am using acra 4.6.2

Comment: I tried using acra 4.9.2 but nothing changed. Still no report at Acralyzer dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> W/ACRA: 403: Client error - request will be discarded

This means the server was reached but denied the action.

Possible reasons include:

- Your authentication is for a user without the required role (which is `reporter`)
- The server denied the connection because of a faulty https configuration

See [Http 403 Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

Answer (score 0):

Add this version

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
}
```

Don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

add the ACRA init in the following overrides method

```
    @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);

    // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
    ACRA.init(this);
    System.out.println("application initialized  ACRA");
}
```

Comment: Tried. Changed version from 4.6.2 to 4.9.2, internet permission is already added. overrided attachBaseContext method to initialise ACRA. In logcat it does not show any report generated or being sent. Last statement in logcat is "isDataSchedulerEnabled():false" and thats it. Still No report at Acralyzer end.

Comment: Here is logcat. ACRA is enabled for com.rashidfaheem.faheemcallrecorder, initializing...
acra I/ACRA: Sending report app_ACRA-approved/2017-09-14T16:18:31.252+05:00-IS_SILENT.stacktrace
:acra E/DataScheduler: isDataSchedulerEnabled():false
W/ACRA: 403: Client error - request will be discarded
acra I/ACRA: Sending report /app_ACRA-approved/16:18:40.066+05:00-IS_SILENT.stacktrace
 W/ACRA: 403: Client error - request will be discarded

Comment: Something about client error 403- request will be discarded. What is this?

Comment: It seems nobody cares to answer.

Comment: I was out of the fields last few days. 403 - Receiving a 403 response is the server telling you, “I’m sorry. I know who you are–I believe who you say you are–but you just don’t have permission to access this resource. Maybe if you ask the system administrator nicely, you’ll get permission. But please don’t bother me again until your predicament changes.”

Comment: You have problem in your server side.

Comment: Thanx Zumry Mohamed, I implemented Crashlytics in my app and its working fine.